# Can we use logical operations on signals when using the systemverilog bind construct?

Tags: bind, system-verilog, logical-operators

can we use logical operations on signals when using the systemverilog bind construct?
i.e. is this legal?

```
bind RTLTOP clk_if clk_if_inst (.clock (rtlclk_A || rtlclk_B) )
```

The base issue, is that I want to use the bind construct to create something like the image seen below.

[image]

The reason I am trying to hack my way ahead, is because I have a fixed RTLTOP (I can't modify that), and I have a highly re-usable interface clk_if that generates events of a particular nature and that can be accessed via easy-to-use methods, therefore I want to be able to use all this good additional infrastructure. However I want the event to be generated based on the OR of the two clocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any expression in a `bind` to connect port as long as it meets the rules for any module instance port connection. The LRM even has an example in section *23.11 Binding auxiliary code to scopes or instances* of a input port connected to the result of a function call with an argument that is a concatenation of signal.

It's easy to drive `input` ports with expressions, but you are limited to concatenation expressions connecting `output` ports.